# tomcat doesn't redirect http to https

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7

I have successfully setup SSL/TLS encryption on my tomcat webserver.

When I navigate to https://abc.example.com everything works fine (connection is secured, page is presented)

Problem: If I navigate to http://abc.example.com immediately the address bar in the browser is changed to servers IP address following by a redirect.cgi:

```
https://1.2.3.4/redirect.cgi?arip=abc.example.com
```

Then the webbrowser tells me that the certificate is not valid (because the IP does not match the CN of the certificate)

I have configured the server.xml file with the redirect to port 443 and wherever as possible the domain name abc.example.com

What could be the reason to this?

INFO: my domain is a subdomain: abc.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dare to claim that this is unrelated to tomcat - or how else does a cgi-script come into play? In case you've configured this yourself, look at the redirect.cgi script. It probably tries to determine the server's name. If you're using Apache httpd, this can typically be configured, otherwise apache defaults to the server's IP address as a name. In this case, Apache typically complains about the missing server name when starting up.

Maybe related: The only place where I found (after a quick search) this redirect.cgi and arip parameter used, was in a ZyXel device - if you're using this one to redirect, that's what you need to configure.

You might get more clues about the actual server by inspecting the HTTP response headers, e.g. with Firebug or a similar tool.

Comment: The domain in not controlled by me. I had the same idea with inspecting the HTTP headers with Firebug and Wireshark. It seems that the domain is already altered before it hits tomcat.